# Should data from database be validated before presenting in UI?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Should we validate the data fetched from the database while displaying in UI?

I am validating form on client side as well as server side before saving.

But should I validate the data before presenting on UI?

Comment: **YES, OF COURSE!** after all - a hacker might have tampered with your database and stored malicious code in your database table - ***ALWAYS*** assume that data is bad - until proven innocent. ***ALWAYS*** validate, never assume data or user input is "valid" and harmless

Comment: How to validate in case of binding grids, Validation process may take long time and hence performance of the page is weaker

Comment: Database theft are not uncommon it can be compromised by SQL-injections, discarded backups  etc. especially when we use shared hosting for our app. If (*IF*) you are sure your DB is secure, you can avoid it.

Comment: This question is too unspecific to answer. If you mean _"Using MVC, is it safe to output user input with `@Html.Raw()`?"_, then the answer is _"No, because it lets one user write HTML (and/or JS) that will be rendered for other users"_, for example.

Answer (score 3):

No, you should validate inputs and work hard to make your validation logic reliable. Hence, you'll be able to blindly rely on your outputs.

Some might argue the opposite. For example, let's say I've defined an input and someone inserts some JavaScript snippet there. **Would I validate the whole text before setting it to the input when that text comes from the database?**. *No*, I would make impossible to execute JavaScript in my UI layer instead.

There're a lot of cases like the one I've described above, where defensive actions should be prefered over validating data before binding it to the UI...

Create/Update actions should store data that have been previously validated and/or sanitized.

In summary, I find some kind of paranoia and bad habit validating outputs: it might mean that your validation isn't validating after all.

### @marc_s commented out in the question:

> YES, OF COURSE! after all - a hacker might have tampered with your
>   database and stored malicious code in your database table - ALWAYS
>   assume that data is bad - until proven innocent. ALWAYS validate,
>   never assume data or user input is "valid" and harmless

I feel that this has other solutions:

1. A good backup strategy and monitoring by a good system's administrator can revert such situation in seconds or few minutes, with few data loss.
2. If a hacker could have tampered a database server, it could also have stolen other parts of the system passwords, or even, drop the database... This could happen because a bad system security configuration, lack of transport-level encryption and many other security details. I wouldn't over-engineer my project to fill the gaps of a good secured environment.

Answer (score 1):

> Should we validate the data fetched from the database while displaying
> in UI?

No, data in your database should already be validated. At each layer moving downstream the data is validated at the UI, the API server, and the database. With the most important level of validation being the database schema, and the UI and API validation layers acting as a way to fail early as to avoid further processing of invalid information.

> But what if a hacker corrupted the data in the database?

Databases have ways to ensure the integrity and reliability of the data (schemas, checksums, redundancy, monitoring tools, etc). The UI and API layers do not need to fail early on validated data.

Comment: "use software that checks your database." - you mean validates the data?

Comment: @Enigmativity - I've updated my answer. I did not mean validate.

Answer (score 1):

You should always validate data when it moves between realms that **you do not fully control**.

For example, you do not control what a user may enter so you must validate their data.

When it comes to a database, if someone else maintains the schema, if data is added using a process you don't control, or if there are new business requirements then you should **validate the data before displaying it to the user**.